# How to combine multiple columns of data into 1 column when pivoting wider in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data set similar in structure to this example one:

```
df <- data.frame(sample=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'),
                 test_1=c(2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4),
                 test_2=c(8, 3, 9, 6, 8, 10, 7, 7),
                 test_3=c(4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4))
view(df)
    
sample test_1 test_2 test_3
 A       2      8       4
 B       1      3       3
 C       4      9       4
 D       3      6       5
 E       5      8       3
 F       2      10      4
 G       1      7       5
 H       4      7       4
```

I want to restructure my data so that the column names are the sample values (A, B, C, etc) and that the row names are test_1, test_2, and test_3.

I have tried to use pivot wider in tidyverse for this but my columns become test_1_A, test_1_B, test_1_C, etc with only 1 unnamed row in the dataset.

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sample, values_from = 2:4)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `pivot_longer(!sample)` first and then `pivot_wider(names_from = sample) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
data.table::transpose(df, make.names = "sample", keep.names = "test")

#     test A B C D E  F G H
# 1 test_1 2 1 4 3 5  2 1 4
# 2 test_2 8 3 9 6 8 10 7 7
# 3 test_3 4 3 4 5 3  4 5 4
```